# jQuery load on click function only work once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to make a group of buttons, they are hidden by default. When one of them are activate they have to...
- show a container
- send values into a PHP container
- load the result in the same container

The problem is that only works once, because if you press another button it only shows its container and hide the rest but it doesn't send the values ​​or load the PHP in the container.

Here is my code, I'm using jQuery 3.4.1:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#grafi').hide();
    $('#g1').hide();
    $('#g2').hide();
    $('#g3').hide();
    $('#g4').hide();

    $('#btn0').click(function(e) {
      $('#grafi').show();
      valor1 = $('#year1').val();
      valor2 = $('#year2').val();
      valor3 = $('#year3').val();

      $("#tabla").load('tablas.php', {
        valor1,
        valor2,
        valor3
      });
      return false;
    });

    // button section that only works once 
    $('#btn1').click(function(e) {
      $('#g1').show();
      $('#g2').hide();
      $('#g3').hide();
      $('#g4').hide();
      valor1 = $('#year1').val();
      valor2 = $('#year2').val();
      valor3 = $('#year3').val();
      $("#g1").load('graficasComGLP.php', {
        valor1,
        valor2,
        valor3
      });
    });

    $('#btn2').click(function(e) {
      $('#g1').hide();
      $('#g2').show();
      $('#g3').hide();
      $('#g4').hide();
      valor1 = $('#year1').val();
      valor2 = $('#year2').val();
      valor3 = $('#year3').val();
      $("#g2").load('graficasComG.php', {
        valor1,
        valor2,
        valor3
      });
    });

    $('#btn3').click(function(e) {
      $('#g1').hide();
      $('#g2').hide();
      $('#g3').show();
      $('#g4').hide();
      valor1 = $('#year1').val();
      valor2 = $('#year2').val();
      valor3 = $('#year3').val();
      $("#g3").load('graficasComD.php', {
        valor1,
        valor2,
        valor3
      });
    });

    $('#btn4').click(function(e) {
      $('#g1').hide();
      $('#g2').hide();
      $('#g3').hide();
      $('#g4').show();
      valor1 = $('#year1').val();
      valor2 = $('#year2').val();
      valor3 = $('#year3').val();
      $("#g4").load('graficasComE.php', {
        valor1,
        valor2,
        valor3
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<html>
  <div align="center" id="grafi">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Graf GLP</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary">Graf Gas</button>
    <button id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary">Graf Diesel</button>
    <button id="btn4" class="btn btn-primary">Graf Elect</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div align="center" id="g1">1</div>
  <div align="center" id="g2">2</div>
  <div align="center" id="g3">3</div>
  <div align="center" id="g4">4</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. You may want to simplify your code and put it Stack Snippets so others can easily reproduce your issue https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Onclick get our next element of that class, set a ticker and as you iterate over the clicks, ticker changes the value of your tags id so you can get it for displaying your loaded section. Not able to show a load in the snipit though, you'll need to add that bit on your end. I show loading some and showing hidden elements on each newly displayed button.

```js
var i = 1;

$('.btn').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function(){
    $(this).prop( "disabled", true );
    $(this).next().css("display", "inline-block");    
    $("#year" + i).each(function(index,value) {
      $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
    });
    i++;
    });
});
```

```css
#btn2,
#btn3,
#btn4,
#year1,
#year2,
#year3,
#year4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="grafi">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Graf GLP</button>
  <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary">Graf Gas</button>
  <button id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary">Graf Diesel</button>
  <button id="btn4" class="btn btn-primary">Graf Elect</button>
</div>
<br>
<div align="center" class="g" id="g1"></div>
<div align="center" class="g" id="g2"></div>
<div align="center" class="g" id="g3"></div>
<div align="center" class="g" id="g4"></div>

<div class="year" id="year1">1994</div>
<div class="year" id="year2">2003</div>
<div class="year" id="year3">1776</div>
<div class="year" id="year4">1984</div>
```